# R Loop Iterating Over Two Lists

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I am attempting to loop over multiple dataframes in R and to extract one column from each dataframe and subtract the value of an element in a separate list. So for example, I want

```
df1$my_new_col<-df1$my_col - my_list[[1]]
df2$my_new_col<-df2$my_col - my_list[[2]] 

etc...
```

The code I have written only extracts the last element in the list and uses it in all of the calculations.

Simply put, I have one list called dates which is a list of dates and another list called spx_list which is a list of annualized returns of the S&P 500.

In my code, I am attempting to loop over each date and extract a data frame of stock returns for that date. In my second loop, I am looping over the list of S&P returns which also correspond to each date and I attempt to subtract each S&P 500 return from each stock's return in that period. My dataframes look like the following when pulled for each date:

For Date 1

```
Ticker            Name                  Total.Return.Y.3..I.
JNS US Equity   JANUS CAPITAL GR    25.27
UNP US Equity   UNION PAC CORP      24.98
CVX US Equity   CHEVRON CORP        24.87
BHI US Equity   BAKER HUGHES A G    24.81
RAI US Equity   REYNOLDS AMERICA    24.72
XOM US Equity   EXXON MOBIL CORP    24.55
CBRE US Equity  CBRE GROUP INC-A    24.43
GT US Equity    GOODYEAR TIRE       24.39
```

For Date 2

```
Ticker            Name                  Total.Return.Y.3..I.
JNS US Equity   JANUS CAPITAL GR    21.03
UNP US Equity   UNION PAC CORP      16.33
CVX US Equity   CHEVRON CORP        12.21
BHI US Equity   BAKER HUGHES A G    47.69
RAI US Equity   REYNOLDS AMERICA    18.39
XOM US Equity   EXXON MOBIL CORP    24.50
CBRE US Equity  CBRE GROUP INC-A    10.81
GT US Equity    GOODYEAR TIRE       11.13
```

And for my S&P data:

```
Ticker     date         Annualized 3
SPX INDEX   3/31/2019   11.22854225
SPX INDEX   12/31/2018  7.041799573
SPX INDEX   9/30/2018   14.91926793
SPX INDEX   6/30/2018   9.629826851
```

List data

```
dates <- list('2019-03-31','2018-12-31','2018-09-30','2018-06-30',
            '2018-03-31','2017-12-31','2017-09-30','2017-06-30',
            '2017-03-31','2016-12-31','2016-09-30','2016-06-30',
            '2016-03-31','2015-12-31','2015-09-30','2015-06-30',
            '2015-03-31','2014-12-31','2014-09-30','2014-06-30',
            '2014-03-31','2013-12-31','2013-09-30','2013-06-30',
            '2013-03-31','2012-12-31','2012-09-30','2012-06-30',
            '2012-03-31','2011-12-31','2011-09-30','2011-06-30',
            '2011-03-31','2010-12-31','2010-09-30','2010-06-30',
            '2010-03-31','2009-12-31','2009-09-30','2009-06-30',
            '2009-03-31','2008-12-31','2008-09-30','2008-06-30',
            '2008-03-31','2007-12-31','2007-09-30','2007-06-30',
            '2007-03-31','2006-12-31','2006-09-30','2006-06-30',
            '2006-03-31','2005-12-31','2005-09-30','2005-06-30',
            '2005-03-31','2004-12-31','2004-09-30','2004-06-30',
            '2004-03-31','2003-12-31','2003-09-30','2003-06-30',
            '2003-03-31','2002-12-31','2002-09-30','2002-06-30',
            '2002-03-31','2001-12-31','2001-09-30','2001-06-30',
            '2001-03-31','2000-12-31','2000-09-30','2000-06-30',
            '2000-03-31')
```

**Code**

```
library(Rblpapi)
blpConnect()

library(dplyr)

spx <- read.csv('spx_3.csv')
spx_list <- as.list(spx$Annualized.3)

totals <- list()
returns <- list()

for(i in dates){

  df <- beqs('ROLLING RETURNS','PRIVATE',date=as.Date(i))
  df_beats <- df%>%
    select(date,Ticker,Total.Return.Y.3..I.)

  df_beats <- na.omit(df_beats)

  for(j in 1:length(spx_list)){

    df_beats$Relative_Performance <- df_beats$Total.Return.Y.3..I.-spx_list[[j]]

    counts <- sum(df_beats$Relative_Performance>0)
    yes <- df_beats%>%
      filter(df_beats$Relative_Performance>0)

    averages <- mean(yes$Total.Return.Y.3..I.)

    totals[[i]] <- counts
    returns[[i]] <- averages

  }
}
```

The goal is to find what percentage of stocks outperformed the S&P 500 in a given year and to find out how much each stock underperformed or outperformed by subtracting the S&P 500's return form the individual stock return.

When the loop is completed, I find that only the last element of the S&p 500 list is used in the calculations, the other returns are skipped over. So in this case, the value of 9.629 is used in the calculation for each dataframe in each time period. Ideally I would like Date 1 Total.Return.Y.3..I to have 11.22 subtracted from it and Date 2$Total.Return.Y.3..I to have 7.04 subtracted from it etc...

I was wondering if anyone might be able help to me extract the data for each period as opposed to just using the last element in the S&P 500 list?

Comment: Are the two lists equal length which appear to be quarterly breakdowns?

Comment: Sorry, yes the two lists are of equal length. The library rblpapi allows for a connection into the Bloomberg Terminal and BEQS is a function that allows you to extract financial data from the terminal. The result of executing the BEQS function is what Date 1 and Date 2 look like above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider handling your process in sets instead of nested loops. Specifically, build a single *beqs* dataset, then merge it with *spx* by date for difference calculation. Finally, aggregate by date for needed *totals* and *returns*.

```
spx <- read.csv('spx_3.csv')

# BUILD LIST OF BEQS DATA FRAMES FOR EACH QUARTERLY DATE
df_list <- lapply(spx$date, function(i) {
      df <- beqs('ROLLING RETURNS', 'PRIVATE', date=as.Date(i))
      df <- df[c("date", "Ticker", "Total.Return.Y.3..I.")]
      return(na.omit(df))
})

# APPEND ALL FOR SINGLE DATA FRAME
df_beqs <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

# MERGE AND ADD NEW COLUMN
final_df <- transform(merge(df_beats, spx, by = "date"),
                      Relative_Performance = `Total.Return.Y.3..I.` - `Annualized 3`)
# FILTER DATA FRAME
final_df <- final_df[final_df$Relative_Performance > 0,]

# AGGREGATE BY DATE FOR MATRIX OUTPUT
agg_df <- aggregate(Total.Return.Y.3..I. ~ date, final_df, 
                    function(x) c(totals = length(x), returns = mean(x)))
```