# R For loop/map2 that iterates over two lists

Tags: r, for-loop, mapping, openxlsx

I've read [this][1] and [this][2], but am unable to adapt it to my use case.  I am trying to use the `openxlsx` function `writeData` to write several dataframes I saved in a vector along with the names of the workbook sheets, also saved in a vector:

```
names_of_worksheets <- c(
  "total_suppliers",
  "nato_fvey_suppliers",
  "us_suppliers",
  "sole_sourcing",
  "single_sourcing",
  "geographic_risk_us_only",
  "foreign_dependence",
  "exposure_to_non_nato_fvey"
  )

names_of_dataframes <- c(
  total_suppliers,
  nato_fvey_suppliers,
  us_suppliers,
  sole_sourcing,
  single_sourcing,
  geographic_risk_us_only,
  foreign_dependence,
  exposure_to_non_nato_fvey
  )
```

The pseudo code I'd like to write is a for loop (which I think I can do in python) that iterates over two lists/vectors:

```
for (name_of_worksheet, name_of_dataframe in names_of_worksheets, names_of_data_frames) {
 writeData(workbook, name_of_worksheet, name_of_dataframe)
}
```

That of course doesn't work.  I've tried `map2` but gotten an error I can't deal with:

```
map2(names_of_worksheets, names_of_dataframes, writeData, workbook)

Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 8
* `.y` has length 25
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!
[1]: [Looping over multiple lists with base R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205479/looping-over-multiple-lists-with-base-r)
[2]: [R Loop Iterating Over Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382464/r-loop-iterating-over-two-lists)

Comment: What does your workbook object look like? It is a list of data.frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use `list()` instead of `c()` to gather your data frames.

The later will take all the columns of the data frames and put them as independent elements in a list (which is why you get inconsistent length error) while the former keeps them as separate elements. The `map2` should work then for simultaneous iteration.

It looks like `writeData` takes workbook as first element and currently your map2 call would use it as third element, so maybe you want to rewrite it as

```
map2(names_of_worksheets, names_of_dataframes, function(x,y) writeData(workbook, x, y))
```